# How to only update one match of an array filter in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

### Problem:

I need to only update one document in the spots available array that has an id of "empty". My previous query was updating all matching sub documents with "empty" as the id; which is no good *Example Below*. So I decided to use aggregation so that I could add a limit stage so that I could only update one item, but come to find out I cannot update the original document with an aggregation. **This leaves the only option to use an array filter that only updates one/first of its matches.** Is this possible? I feel like there has to be a way to only update one match on an array filter and if there isn't this is definitely something that should be added.

### My code:

*This code updates every object with "empty"*

```js
        const client = await clientPromise;
            const db = client.db();
            // const query = db.collection('events').aggregate(agg);


            const query = await db.collection('events').updateOne({
                _id: new ObjectId("6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"),
                createdBy: new ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690"),
                "weights.weight": 12
            },
                {
                    $set: {
                        "weights.$.spotsAvailable.$[el2]": {
                            "name": "Wayne Wrestler",
                            "userId": new ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690")
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    arrayFilters: [{ "el2": { "userId": "empty" } }]
                })
```

---

### Example documents:

#### Event:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"
  },
  "name": "test",
  "createdBy": {
    "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
  },
  "description": "testing",
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1645488000000"
    }
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  "weights": [
    {
      "spotsAvailable": [
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        },
        {
          "name": "empty",
          "userId": "empty"
        }
      ],
      "weight": 12
    },
    {
      "spotsAvailable": [
        {
// only one of these should've been updated, but both were
          "name": "Wayne Wrestler",
          "userId": {
            "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Wayne Wrestler",
          "userId": {
            "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
          }
        }
      ],
      "weight": 15
    }
  ],
  "eventApplicants": [
    {
      "userId": {
        "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
      },
      "name": "Wayne Wrestler",
      "weight": 12
    }
  ]
}
```

#### User:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636c1778f1d09191074f9690"
  },
  "name": "Wayne Wrestler",
  "email": "wakywayne80@gmail.com",
  "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ALm5wu32gXjDIRxncjjQA9I4Yl-sjFH5EWsTlmvdM_0kiw=s96-c",
  "emailVerified": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1670864727212"
    }
  },
  "createdEvents": [
    {
      "createdEventName": "test",
      "createdEventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1645488000000"
        }
      },
      "createdEventDescription": "testing",
      "createdEventWeights": [
        {
          "weight": "12",
          "filled": [
            false,
            false,
            false
          ]
        },
        {
          "weight": "15",
          "filled": [
            false,
            false
          ]
        }
      ],
      "createdEventId": {
        "$oid": "6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"
      }
    }
  ],
  "userSignedUpEvents": [],
  "availableWeights": [
    1,
    123
  ],
  "signedUpEvents": [
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "636c722f67642c30dc5ffc30"
      },
      "eventName": "Utah",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1667913330000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "636c722f67642c30dc5ffc30"
      },
      "eventName": "Utah",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1667913330000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "637ec484ac2d675b30590b47"
      },
      "eventName": "Maybe?",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1672272000000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "636c722f67642c30dc5ffc30"
      },
      "eventName": "Utah",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1667913330000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "638d5274628db2a7bf61df49"
      },
      "eventName": "Eva's",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1698019200000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "636c722f67642c30dc5ffc30"
      },
      "eventName": "Utah",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1667913330000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "6398a922abb5c168ede595fb"
      },
      "eventName": "Nikko's event",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1670976000000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "6398a922abb5c168ede595fb"
      },
      "eventName": "Nikko's event",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1670976000000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"
      },
      "eventName": "test",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1645488000000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"
      },
      "eventName": "test",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1645488000000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"
      },
      "eventName": "test",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1645488000000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    },
    {
      "eventId": {
        "$oid": "6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"
      },
      "eventName": "test",
      "eventDate": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1645488000000"
        }
      },
      "accepted": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried:

1. Pluging in variables without the `new ObjectId` syntax
2. Plugin in variables with the `new ObjectId` syntax
3. Using the exact same hardcoded values that I got from copying the aggregation code from compass for the node driver

All of these either don't work or result in every subdocument with "empty" getting filled

Comment: how about using findOneAndUpdate cmd ? if you re not using mongoose i think it was findAndModify cmd in mongoDb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use update with pipeline:

Since this is a double nested array, it is easier to do it in two steps - internal and external

1. First create the "external" item to replace in `weights` array and call it `newItem`. It is calculated using `$reduce` which allow us to manipulate the internal array while looping on it.
2. Replace the relevant item on `weights` array with our `newItem` using `$map` with `$cond`

```
db.collection.update(
  {_id: ObjectId("6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"), "weights.weight": 12},
  [
    {$set: {
      newItem: {$reduce: {
          input: {$getField: {
              input: {$first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$weights",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$item.weight", 12]}
                  }
              }},
              field: "spotsAvailable"
          }},
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$and: [
                      {$eq: ["$$this.userId", "empty"]},
                      {$not: {$in: [ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690"), "$$value.userId"]}}
                  ]},
                  [{
                      name: "Wayne Wrestler",
                      userId: ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690")
                  }],
                  ["$$this"]
                ]}
            ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {
      weights: {$map: {
          input: "$weights",
          in: {$cond: [
              {$eq: ["$$this.weight", 12]},
              {$mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {spotsAvailable: "$newItem"}
              ]},
              "$$this"
          ]}
      }},
      newItem: "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/74LxOAPfi6r)

Comment: Honestly, I think what I am experiencing is what would happen if you met someone from the future lol. I am going to try to not ask a million questions so I will start with 2. 
1. What does the *double* $$ do? I am familiar with $ representing an item in an array, but not $$
2. Is this code going to work in the nodeJS driver?

Comment: I'll take it as a compliment :). 1. Operators that loops over arrays (`$map`, `$filter`, `$reduce`) uses `$$` to reference the current item of the loop, so `$$item.weight` is the `weight` of the current item in the `$filter` operation. `$$value` is the current value of a `$reduce` operator while reducing. There are also special cases like (`$$NOW`, `$$ROOT`, `$$REMOVE`). 2. Sure.

Comment: So everyone I have talked to about this issue said you cannot update the original document using aggregation... Is the reason why we are able to do this because we aren't really using an aggregation because we start the operation with ```$set```? And where can I go in the docs about using this $set aggregation and all of these operators? I can't find anything on them and I definitely want to learn this as it looks very useful. **And it definitely was a compliment**

Comment: Also, what is the $not doing? And aren't we not supposed to use ```update()``` anymore? I thought MongoDB wants us to use updateMany() or updateOne().

Comment: Everyone is wrong :) you can update using aggregation (with a [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) step) just like @ray's answer here. You can also use update with pipeline just like in my answer. You can find all of these operators [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: It is better to use `updateOne()` or `updateMany()`, but they are not supported in the mongodb playground, so for convenience I use  `update()` which you should replace on your case. `$not` is switching he condition, so it will find the case where the objectId is **not** `$in`  "$$value.userId"

Comment: We are not using proper "aggregation" because we are using the family of `update()` and not `.aggregate()`. We can still use a pipeline...

Answer (score 1):

You can first `$unwind` the `weights` for easier processing first. Use `$reduce` to iterate through the `weights.spotsAvailable` array and use a compound object to store the result and a flag to indicate whether it is updated or not. Finally use the result to `$merge` back to the original document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("6398c34ca67dbe3286452f23"),
      createdBy: ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690"),
      "weights.weight": 12,
      "weights.spotsAvailable.userId": "empty"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$weights"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "results": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$weights.spotsAvailable",
          "initialValue": {
            result: [],
            updated: false
          },
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      false,
                      "$$value.updated"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "empty",
                      "$$this.userId"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                result: {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    "$$value.result",
                    [
                      {
                        "name": "Wayne Wrestler",
                        "userId": ObjectId("636c1778f1d09191074f9690")
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                updated: true
              },
              "else": {
                result: {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    "$$value.result",
                    [
                      "$$this"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                updated: "$$value.updated"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "weights.spotsAvailable": "$results.result",
      "results": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "name": {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      "createdBy": {
        $first: "$createdBy"
      },
      "description": {
        $first: "$description"
      },
      "date": {
        $first: "$date"
      },
      "location": {
        $first: "$location"
      },
      "weights": {
        $push: "$weights"
      },
      "eventApplicants": {
        $first: "$eventApplicants"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vCMXo9uLYF0)